# Extracting Multiple Elements with same html criteria in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm novice with python and beautiful so this answer may be obvious.

I'm using beautiful soup to parse the following html and extract the Date.

```
html='''
<p><strong>Event:</strong>Meeting</p>
<p><strong>Date:</strong> Mon, Apr 25, 2016, 11 am</p>
<p><strong>Price:</strong>$20.00</p>

<p><strong>Event:</strong>Convention</p>
<p><strong>Date:</strong> Mon, May 2, 2016, 11 am</p>
<p><strong>Price:</strong>$25.00</p>

<p><strong>Event:</strong>Dance</p>
<p><strong>Date:</strong> Mon, May 9, 2016, 11 am</p>
<p><strong>Price:</strong>Free</p>
'''
```

I parsed the date when there is only one date using the following code but having a hard time when encountering multiple dates (only gets one date).

```
date_raw = html.find_all('strong',string='Date:')
date = str(date_raw.p.nextSibling).strip()
```

Is there a way to do this in bs4 or should I use regular expressions.  Any other suggestions?

Desired list output:

['Mon, Apr 25, 2016, 11 am','Mon, May 2, 2016, 11 am','Mon, May 9, 2016, 11 am']

Answer (score 1):

I would probably iterate of every found element and append it to a list.  Something like this maybe (untested):

```
date_list = []
date_raw = html.find_all('strong',string='Date:')

for d in date_raw:
    date = str(d.p.nextSibling).strip()
    date_list.append(date)

print date_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help.  I posted the answer.  I had to put in the index and iterate off of that.

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake...fixed it:

```
for x in range(0,len(date_raw)):
    date_add = date_raw[x].next_sibling.strip()
    date_list.append(date_add)
    print (date_add)
```

Comment: Good you spotted your error. FYI iterating over `range(len(something))` is considered an anti-pattern in Python. Ed Dunn's answer with `for d in date_raw` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  Could you elaborate on how this is an anti-pattern?  I see it as redundant but not counter productive in terms of logic.  Is it an anti-pattern because it takes extra unnecessary steps?

Comment: Trey,
I reworked the code.  This doesn't look right but its the only way I could get it to work.

     ' for x in date_raw:
          date_add = date_raw[date_raw.index(x)].next_sibling.strip()
          date_list.append(date_add)'

Comment: `for x in date_raw:
 date_add = date_raw[date_raw.index(x)].next_sibling.strip()
 date_list.append(date_add)`

Comment: I believe `date_raw[date_raw.index(x)]` could simply be `x`.